# Remove the first two columns from a csv file with REGEX

Tags: regex, csv

I am having trouble removing the first two columns from a CSV file using REGEX. Usually I would have used the expression "^(?:[^,]+,){2}", but the structure of my file prevents me from doing that (there may be null columns).

Here is an example of my data:
https://regex101.com/r/Rzi8de/1

The desired result is:

```
value3,value4
value3,value4
value3,value4
,value4
```

I thank you in advance!

Comment: That approach won't work if your CSV columns can include commas: `"a,b",x,y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem with your snippet is using `+` (1 or more repetitions) instead of `*` (zero or more repetitions). What about something like this?

```
^([^,]*,){2}
```

"At the beginning of a string, match two occurrences of anything-except-comma (including *nothing*, as denoted by `*`) followed by a comma"